# Let's have a meeting conversation through Skype

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm pretty sure that ELL could be a very useful site for those who are learning English. However, for speaking and listening skills it wouldn't offer anythings.

As far as we have weekly writing chat, which users choose a subject and have free discussion about it. This is good IMO. However I should improve my speaking and listening skills. I searched on-line Skype users through Google and some other sites to have a free discussion with whom. Unfortunately there's no user spending some time for such a free discussion.

My suggestion would be let's have a weekly free discussion through Skype. Willing users may want to leave their username and other users call them.

I'd be glad to know your thoughts.

Comment: Do we have a weekly writing chat (or chat room?) on ELL? (That's new to me!)

Comment: Yes, every Tuesday on 9PM.

Comment: It's on another stack, perhaps. (But that's okay! Anything that gives us more chances to use English is useful!)

Comment: @Dam I'm not that subtle. The weekly writing chat happens at . . . guess what, writers.SE chatroom.